# Streaming services on Shabbat and holy days

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, internet, torah-service

More and more non-traditional congregations stream their Shabbat and Yom Tov services, for the benefit of hospital patients and shut-ins.

If done automatically, or managed by Gentiles, or started before the holiday, would this be halachically allowed?

Note this relevant ruling:

> ...R’ Moshe Feinstein (in a letter to R’ Yisroel Rozen of the Tzomet Institute) wrote that as the data is not being permanently recorded, it is at worst a Derabanan [prohibition].

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12160/can-you-leave-video-chat-on-over-shabbos and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52546/waving-at-a-security-camera-on-shabbat/91742

Comment: Perhaps if the streaming is done or started before Shabbat it is ok. Many Reform congregations stream their serves on Yom Kippur.

Comment: Maybe they could send the service via internet after Shabbat, instead of streaming it live.

Comment: Lifnei ever would be a pretty obvious issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: I edited a question because from R"M answer it is clear that we should differentiate between different types of videoing on Shabbos, according to its goals and features. Therefore this question, that focuses on a specific case is absolutely legit. Many many distant Derabans might be allowed for bringing masses closer to shuls and the tradition, especially if this is an alternative to watching TV or YTube.