# Surveillance Cameras on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Is it permissible to walk past an active surveillance camera on Shabbos that is being monitored? Does it matter for what purpose it's being monitored?

Note: this question: [Unintentional closing and opening of electrical circuits on shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/unintentional-closing-and-opening-of-electrical-circuits-on-shabbat) asks about the issue of cameras almost exclusvely regarding the issue of circuits, but I am asking whether this is forbidden for any reason,not limited to the issue of circuits.

For example, perhaps the recording of the events are included in the category of writing/

Comment: Pesik Reisha D'lo Necha Leh possibly

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6523 Rabbi Yoel Liberman also cites the Shemiras Shabbos KeHilchasa (Pg 380 in the new edition) that its ok to walk in front of a security camera on Shabbos.  See there for a more lengthy explination.